# What is the value of $\Gamma(\mathrm{i})$ ?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

What is  the value of $\Gamma(\mathrm{i})$ ? $\Gamma(z)$ is Gamma function. Here $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$.Can you help me with this problem ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#Imaginary_unit

Comment: M.B., why don't you make this comment into an answer?

Comment: Sure, I can do that.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia the value is:
$\Gamma(i) = (-1+i)! \approx -0.1549 - 0.4980i$.

Now from J.M.'s comment we know that $|\Gamma(i)|^2 = \frac{\pi}{\sinh \pi}$ but I do not think $\Gamma(i)$ can be expressed by elementary functions.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#Imaginary_unit

**edit**: more identities (including the one above) can be found at 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

Comment: So people don't have to click on links: there is the identity $|\Gamma(i)|^2=\dfrac{\pi}{\sinh\pi}$, so that takes care of the absolute value at least. The argument, however, doesn't lend itself well to a simple expression...

Comment: @J.M. This is a very nice closed expression, which one will, however, not find when clicking on the wikipedia link, unless I've overlooked it. So do you happen to have a source for this particular expression?.

Comment: @Thomas: under 'additional identities': http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

Comment: @M.B. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

So: a method for computing it.  The integral formula converges to compute $\Gamma(1+i)$, then the functional equation will give us $\Gamma(i)$ from that.
$$
\Gamma(i) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{e} ^{-x} \operatorname{sin} \bigl(\operatorname{log} (x)\bigr) d x - i \int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{e} ^{-x} \operatorname{cos} \bigl(\operatorname{log} (x)\bigr) d x
$$

Comment: Now, I wonder if any computer software or book of integral tables lists $\int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{e} ^{-x} \operatorname{sin} \bigl(\operatorname{log} (x)\bigr) d x = \mathrm{Re}\Gamma(i)$ as a "closed form" for that integral?