# Is there a closed form for $\Gamma(i)$?

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

I know that
$$\Gamma(z)\cdot\Gamma(z^*)=|\Gamma(z)|^2\tag{1}$$
and
$$\Gamma (z)\cdot \Gamma (1-z) =\frac{\pi }{\sin{\pi z}}\tag{2}$$
but I still can't find closed form for $\Gamma(i)$

Comment: I don't think there is a closed formula. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Imaginary_unit.

Comment: From your two expressions (and using $\Gamma(1-z)=-z\,\Gamma(-z)$) you may deduce that $\,\displaystyle|\Gamma(i)|^2=\frac {\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$

Comment: I know that, but I have no idea what to do with the phase.How to get it?

Comment: I don't know a closed form except for the modulus (use at least $\Gamma$ or the Barnes G-function seems necessary). See [Alpha's results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28i%29) for more...

Comment: It is definitely not a rigorous answer, but the argument "if it existed, it'd be [on this page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(i)&t=crmtb01)" hints there is none...

Comment: Related (but not an answer): [What is the value of $\Gamma(\mathrm{i})$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153719/)